# Intel microcode is not updating

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, intel

Trying to update Intel microcode to 03/12/2018 release (Version: 20180312) with the following procedure:

```
1. extract files from downloaded tarball
2. cp -v intel-ucode/* /lib/firmware/intel-ucode/ 
3. echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload
4. dracut -vvf
5. reboot
```

but nothing changes. Before update:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep microcode
microcode       : 0x13
```

After update:

```
# dmesg | grep microcode
[    1.096790] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206c2, pf=0x1, revision=0x13
[    1.096829] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x206c2, pf=0x1, revision=0x13
[    1.096851] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x206c2, pf=0x1, revision=0x13
[    1.096875] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x206c2, pf=0x1, revision=0x13
[    1.096965] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

I'm doing that to fix 'Spectre variant 2'. The spectre-meltdown-checker.sh shows the following:

```
CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection] aka 'Spectre Variant 2'
* Mitigation 1
  * Kernel is compiled with IBRS/IBPB support:  YES
  * Currently enabled features
    * IBRS enabled for Kernel space:  NO
    * IBRS enabled for User space:  NO
    * IBPB enabled:  NO
* Mitigation 2
  * Kernel has branch predictor hardening (arm):  NO
  * Kernel compiled with retpoline option:  NO
  * Kernel compiled with a retpoline-aware compiler:  NO
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (Your kernel is compiled with IBRS but your CPU microcode is lacking support to successfully mitigate the vulnerability)
```

CPU is the following: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620  @ 2.40GHz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest microcode package doesn’t contain any updates for your [Westmere EP CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/47925/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5620-12M-Cache-2_40-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI?q=E5620) since the previous release in November 2017; see [the changelog](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27591/Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-File) for details. It therefore doesn’t contain any Spectre fixes for your particular CPU.

According to [Intel’s communication](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/04/04/intel_spectre_microcode_updates/), Westmere fixes for Spectre v2 *are* available, but presumably they’re following their previously-established pattern of shipping them to OEMs before making them available in the microcode package. The latest [microcode revision guidance](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/04/microcode-update-guidance.pdf) (from April 2) indicates that Westmere EP will be getting revision 0x1E, presumably in the next microcode package update. The previous [guidance](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/03/microcode-update-guidance.pdf) listed the Westmere EP as beta with revision 0x1D.

Comment: Thank you @StephenKitt for such a quick and full answer!

Comment: Stephen, actually, I can see my cpu in "valid products" list on [Intel download page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27591/Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-File?product=47925)

Comment: Yes, the CPU is listed in the valid products because the package contains a microcode update for your CPU (revision 0x13); however that update hasn’t changed since the previous version, 20171117, so it doesn’t contain the Spectre fixes.

Comment: Thanks again for explanation, @StephenKitt! So, according to Intel's latest "Microcode revision guidance" they'll release 0x1E microcode revision for Westmere EP, right?

Comment: Indeed, that’s how I read the document.

Comment: Thank you. @StephenKitt, perhaps that's not the place to ask this question, but I'll try... I have another machine with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz and, according the guidance on 6 March, the cpu microcode update for that version should be released with revision 0x42c. I've installed the microcode update (r20180312), but microcode had been updated to 0x713 version and I still cannot use Spectre variant 2 fix.

Comment: Well, re-read the documentation again.. The revision for my CPU (Xeon E5-2420) in latest update package is right (0x713). But if the revision is updated to the latest version (0x713), why I still cannot use variant 2 fix?..